# How to lag a time variable and keep the format?

Tags: r, time, lag

I want to lag the time variable itself, the format changes, simple example:

```
data<-data.frame(number=seq(1:5), 
      datetime=seq(as.POSIXct("2015/06/12"),as.POSIXct("2015/06/16"),by="1 day"))

   number   datetime
1      1 2015-06-12
2      2 2015-06-13
3      3 2015-06-14
4      4 2015-06-15
5      5 2015-06-16
```

What I want:

```
  number   datetime datetime.lag
1      1 2015-06-12           NA
2      2 2015-06-13   2015-06-12
3      3 2015-06-14   2015-06-13
4      4 2015-06-15   2015-06-14
5      5 2015-06-16   2015-06-15


data$datetime.lag<-c(NA, head(data$datetime, -1))
```

What I get:

```
  number   datetime datetime.lag
1      1 2015-06-12           NA
2      2 2015-06-13   1434092400
3      3 2015-06-14   1434178800
4      4 2015-06-15   1434265200
5      5 2015-06-16   1434351600
```

Why the format changes? any better suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `shift` from the devel version of `data.table` i.e. `v.1.9.5`.  The default `type` is `lag` and `n` is 1.   Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, lagdt:= shift(datetime)][]
#    number   datetime      lagdt
#1:      1 2015-06-12       <NA>
#2:      2 2015-06-13 2015-06-12
#3:      3 2015-06-14 2015-06-13
#4:      4 2015-06-15 2015-06-14
#5:      5 2015-06-16 2015-06-15
```

We can also get multiple lags

```
setDT(data)[, paste0('lagDT', 1:2) :=shift(datetime, 1:2)][]
#    number   datetime     lagDT1     lagDT2
#1:      1 2015-06-12       <NA>       <NA>
#2:      2 2015-06-13 2015-06-12       <NA>
#3:      3 2015-06-14 2015-06-13 2015-06-12
#4:      4 2015-06-15 2015-06-14 2015-06-13
#5:      5 2015-06-16 2015-06-15 2015-06-14
```

Answer (score 2):

Your date is being coerced because `NA` isn't recognised as the same class as `POSIXct`. Try:

```
data$datetime.lag <- c(as.POSIXct(NA), head(data$datetime, -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

When I need a lag like this, I'm often already using `dplyr`, in which is a`lag` function that meets your needs:

```
mutate(dat, lagdt=lag(datetime))
##   number   datetime      dtlag      lagdt
## 1      1 2015-06-12 2015-06-12       <NA>
## 2      2 2015-06-13 2015-06-13 2015-06-12
## 3      3 2015-06-14 2015-06-14 2015-06-13
## 4      4 2015-06-15 2015-06-15 2015-06-14
## 5      5 2015-06-16 2015-06-16 2015-06-15
```

Equivalently, depending on your acceptance of the `%>%` pipe operator ([*ceci n'est pas un pipe*](https://github.com/smbache/magrittr)):

```
dat %>% mutate(dtlag=lag(datetime))
##   number   datetime      dtlag
## 1      1 2015-06-12       <NA>
## 2      2 2015-06-13 2015-06-12
## 3      3 2015-06-14 2015-06-13
## 4      4 2015-06-15 2015-06-14
## 5      5 2015-06-16 2015-06-15
```